# Pgfplot won't compile more than 6 curves on the same plot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot with pgfplots 12 curves on the same plot. The curves are given by 12 csv tables named "curve_01","curve_02" etc., about 3000 points each. 
To reduce computational time I reduce the number of points giving the "each nth point" option. I used also externalization with shell escape command.

Here my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}


\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[each nth point=1000, filter discard warning=false, unbounded coords=discard ,cycle list name=color list]
\foreach \x in {01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12}
 \addplot table[col sep=comma, x index=2,y index=0] {../../Test_DCBII/curve_\x.txt};
\end{axis}



  \end{tikzpicture}


  \end{document}
```

The problem is that this code plots only 6 out of 12 curves needed, no matter if I reduce the points to calculate. How can I fix this??

The files can be found [here](http://multiupload.biz/rg7hel6folya/Test_DCBII_MultiUpload.biz.rar.html) (i uploaded just 9 files)

Comment: could you post just one of the data files you're using, e.g `Test_DCBII/curve_01.txt`?

Comment: I just edited the answer

Comment: Ahem if it's only a memory limit compile with `lualatex`.

Comment: No it's not a problem relative to memory (I don't have any error mesages) the problem is that this code works only with the first six curves; the others won't plot even if I refresh  multiple times. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Won't the option `each nth point=1000` make it skip ~1000 points in plot? Could it be that some data sets have less than 1000 points? Did you try removing that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented out line 7 (starting with "carico,tempo,...") from your original files and then the plot looks fine, with 9 curves, *without* externalizing the plots.

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 and compiled with TexWorks Version 0.5 r.952 (Debian).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[each nth point=1000, filter discard warning=false, unbounded coords=discard ,cycle list name=color list]
            \foreach \x in {01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09}
                 \addplot table[col sep=comma, x index=2,y index=0] {curve_\x.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot with 9 curves]

Comment: Nice, next time i will apply a better formatting method for my tables ;). Now I will try some modification, thank you.